# HTML JavaScript-Posición de un Canvas sobre un Video

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi Canvas se me posicione sobre la etiqueta `video` con exactamente el mismo tamaño al tomar una foto. O si hay alguna manera de hacer que se tome la foto y te de el preview sin un canvas mucho mejor. Les paso mi código para que observen. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```js
var fot;
//Funcion para lanzar la camara, Funcionando.
function activateCamera() {
 var video = document.querySelector("#camaraOn");


 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMEdia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
    }

    function handleVideo(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }


    function videoError(e) {
        alert("La camara No esta funcionando Permita el acceso")
    }
  canvas= document.querySelector("#fotoTomada");

 canvas.style.visibility="hidden";

}


//Funcion para capturar el streaming
function tomarFoto() {
    var video = document.querySelector("#camaraOn");
    canvas= document.querySelector("#fotoTomada");
    canvas.width=1080;
    canvas.height=650;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video,0,0,1080,650);
    fot= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 video.style.visibility="hidden";
 canvas.style.visibility="visible";



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> SnapDCU </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </head>
  <header>

    <nav>
      <div class="barraMenu">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="current"> <a href="#"> Inicio </a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Subir Foto Externa </a> </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <body onload="activateCamera()">
    <style>
    .canvasCamara{
      position: relative;
    }
    .canvasCamara>.botonesAccion{
        background: url('css/img/shotpng.png') bottom center no-repeat;
       height: 128px;
       left: 50%;
       margin: -64px 0 0 -64px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 85%;
       border: 15px solid transparent;
       width: 128px;
       z-index: 1;
    }

    #fotoTomada{
      visibility: hidden;
      
    }

    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="canvasCamara">
        <video autoplay="true" width="1080" id="camaraOn" height="650"> </video>
        <button class="botonesAccion" onclick="tomarFoto()" type="button" id="btnTake" name="btnTake"></button>
      </div>
        <canvas id="fotoTomada" width="1" height="1"></canvas>

    </div>


<script src="js/script.js"> </script>

  </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay nada de malo en usar canvas para mostrar una imagen; igual puedes hacerlo de la manera clásica vía `img`. Cuando se tome la foto debes obtener las coordenadas del `video` y luego, crear el `canvas` o `img`. Luego, debes hacer el  elemento absoluto y ponerle un `left` y `top` respectivo a las coordenadas del `video`.

Por ejemplo:

```
btnTakePhoto.addEventListener('click', function () {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let { left, top } = video.getBoundingClientRect();

  canvas.width = '600';
  canvas.height = '400';

  canvas.style.left = `${left}px`;
  canvas.style.top = `${top}px`;
  canvas.style.position = 'absolute';

  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 600, 400);

  videoStream.getTracks()[0].stop();
  video.remove();
});
```

La instrucción `videoStream.getTracks()[0].stop();` detiene el uso de la cámara luego de tomar la foto. Si no quieres este comportamiento, no la pongas.

---

[Demo disponible](https://jsbin.com/wexuyivisi/edit?output).

Comment: Excelente, me funciono de maravilla. Gracias!

Comment: +1 por el uso de destructuring assignement